# Theme(Zemez template monster) not supporting Multi-select Layered Navigation extension in magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, theme, layered-navigation, multiselect-attribute

I have been searching for a free and open source Multiple select Layered Navigation.
I found this
https://www.magesolution.com/magento2-layered-navigation.html
extension which working 100% fine and fulfils my requirement on Blank magento or magento luma theme

[image]

As u can see i select multiple categories and attributes as well and results is showing without load using Ajax.

But Problem is i have installed Zemez's theme from template monster.
Theme is not supporting this extension and i am getting results as
[image]

As u can see in image after the selection of Brand attribute brand got disappears and filtering with single select and also loading the page not using Ajax.
i have done several changes in app/design/Vendor/theme/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/
state.phtml ,layer.phtml, view.phtml but i am not getting expected results.
Please help to remove theme's override on methods and to extension successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to be told that third party stuff is not in scope.

It is quite a trial and error slog to "undo" layout changes and quite a bit will probably be in layout xml files but there's 2 things perhaps worth trying:

If the template monster theme actually installed extra modules as part of the package, disable any navigation sounding ones. That could fix a lot. << in your case I would suspect that Ajax Catalog Filter - you need to turn that off and test. Hopefully you can turn it off in the normal config, many modules have an "enable yes/no", otherwise you have to go via module disable.

If that didnt then it is playing with layout files. You will need to create layout files in your theme that fix the layout changes made by the parent theme. Not just templates.

But at that point if you bought that theme file a support ticket with zemez - they probably can fix it quick

Comment: Thanks for guidance, can you plz explain me more specifically im a newbie in magento.you talked about Layout files and other things but honestly i dont know how to manage those xml files and how edit them so plz can u guide me from scratch.

Comment: It's a lot of "it depends" on the exact scenario - which Zemez theme is it, actually?

Comment: OK Zemez_EVA is the theme https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/69471.html

Comment: see the first suggestion in my answer? You have 2 modules doing the same thing.
Either disable the theme's "Ajax Catalog Filter" and test. Or disable the Magesolution one and check that the theme supplied one is not also ok for your needs.
Either way all caches need clearing including javascript

Comment: if i disabled the theme's Layered Navigation its applyinh phtml files of  Magento_Layered Navigation

Comment: yes. that is normal. The Magesolution module works on top of these.
If that still doesnt work go to Zemez support

Comment: Zemez supports says we dont guaretee 3rd party extension

Answer (score 0):

A third party plugin will never be guaranteed to work with another third party plugin, unless you're willing to do some custom development to resolve this I wouldn't have any expectation of it ever working.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by disabling the Zemez_AjaxCatalog extension (php bin/magento module:disable Zemez_AjaxCatalog --clear-static-content). After that, re compiled magento (php bin/magento setup:di:compile) and then flushed the cache in the admin view.

Since both extensions are third partys they won't interact with each others in a nice way.

Hope it helps.

PS: I used MAGENTO 2 LAYERED NAVIGATION AJAX FILTER WITH MULTI SELECT from WeltPixel.